# How should I set scrollbar properties

Tags: css

```
BODY
{
    SCROLLBAR-FACE-COLOR: #e9e9e9;
    SCROLLBAR-HIGHLIGHT-COLOR: #1679aa;
    SCROLLBAR-SHADOW-COLOR: #1679aa;
    SCROLLBAR-DLIGHT-COLOR: #cccccc;
    SCROLLBAR-ARROW-COLOR: #1679aa;
    SCROLLBAR-TRACK-COLOR: #dee3e7;
    SCROLLBAR-DARKSHADOW-COLOR: #03276e;
}
```

I tried to run a web application in visual studio 2008...
The above CSS file creates err.
'SCROLLBAR-FACE-COLOR not a know CSS property name'
I got the err for all the scroll bar properties above...
How should I proceed?

Comment: I never thought to this day that I'd ever see uppercase CSS selectors and properties...

Comment: Did anyone else just have a flashback to web-development from 10 years ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. There's no point to doing this since:

- Scrollbars are browser UI elements and you shouldn't screw with their styles as that might confuse users
- Only IE and Opera support it and even then my guess is that newer versions are going to drop support for this as well

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you shouldn't ever modify the scrollbar styles as it's intrusive and no one else really does it.

Your OS should be rendering it. In addition, it's non-standard and some browsers might not even support it.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar is not a valid CSS property. You should delete those declarations from your CSS file. Other thing is that not every browsers can interpret it. As I know only Internet Explorer and Opera can.

So just delete them :)