# Graphic Scrollbar modification on Auto DIV Scroller script

Tags: javascript, css, html

We're using this autoscroller script: http://scripterlative.com/files/autodivscroll.htm (the bottom version).

However, we got really stuck since we don't know how to replace the moving "scrollbar" on the scroller side with a pure and simple line with up arrow on top and bottom arrow on bottom.

Functions wise we want this sidebar to behave exactly like the original sidebar and of course be cross browser compatible. We just want to get rid of the original scrollbar and replace it with a much cleaner and more stylish style.

Is this doable?! How?

Best regards Stefan

Comment: Do you mean the scrollbar of the textarea?

Comment: Yeah - I mean the right side scrollbar of the textarea, see http://scripterlative.com/files/autodivscroll.htm - bottom example - the scrollbar on the right side.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the script itself. How the scrollbar looks depends on the browser you use. See for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500920/how-should-i-set-scrollbar-properties-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Just found [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) on AjaxRain.

Implementing an autoscroll would take some coding, but should definitely be possible by just sending the click messages to the div manually so that it would do the scrolling. If it looks like this will suit your needs, I'd chip in with some additional implementation code. That topic may actually be better suited for another question, if you decide on jScrollPane.

Edit: updated link above. also, there are demos there for scrolling on [hover](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrow_hover.html) and clicking on a link to jump to an [anchor](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/anchors.html). Custom code for an autoscroll should be relatively simple to write from there.

Comment: Hi,

We're open for suggestions, but chose to use this script since the customer needs
- Autoscroll initiation directly
- Scroll back to top when done, and repeat
- Smooth scroll
- On mouse over text/content = stop text
- On mouse off text/content = resume scroll

The only thing that bothers the customer at this stage is actually the sidebar. It's not good looking and they want a much cleaner style of the sidebar basicly.

Comment: if you just want CSS, check the link in z00bs comment on your question. but, the CSS stuff isn't very consistent across browsers or OS, fyi. my answer was more about how to completely customize things with a "manual" ui.. because you said the thing about simple arrows.

Comment: Zanlok - so what are you saying? ;-)  That if we would replace the current script with jScrollPane, this wouldn't be a problem any more? Does jScrollPane have all the functionality thats needed? (See above) How much time/work is it to make this work?

Comment: That's kind of a separate question, but I'll try to answer it. I would say it would be a 1 hour job assuming someone had experience with that script and there wasn't a lot of complication behind the scenes on how your markup is presented. The easy part is to get your textbox content into the scrolling div, then you'd just need to write the autoscroll function - using maybe a recurring window.setTimeout every 250ms or so. However, you'd probably want to budget nearly a full day for your first go at integrating that script.

Comment: So basicly, there is no way that by using Javascript or something simular to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left this could be accomplished?

Comment: My answer is not to use the traditionally-rolled textarea input type, and to implement a custom div. What's nice about the jScrollPane I've suggested is that 98% of the work is done for you, and it's an active project that should have great browser compatability. Based upon this, any chance you'd accept my answer?